# Assign layer style from qml file

Tags: qgis-3, python-3, qml

I am adding a number of spatial csv files as layers and want to assign a qml layer style.

```
import processing


# User Dialog to pick Import_QGIS folder
Folder_Path = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(caption="Pick the folder 'Import_QGIS'.")

# Folder_Path for uri
Folder_Path_uri = "file:///"+ Folder_Path + "/"

# Make a tuple with the filenames
import os
i=0
my_tuple=[]
for file in os.listdir(Folder_Path):
    First3Letters = file[0:2]
    try:
        int(First3Letters) < 300
        print(file)
        my_tuple.append(file)
        i+=1
    except:
        continue
iNum = int(i)
print(iNum)

for x in range(iNum):
    try:
        uri = Folder_Path_uri + my_tuple[x] + "?type=csv&delimiter=,&detectTypes=yes&xField=X_Wert_Pos&yField=Y_Wert_Pos&crs=epsg:25832&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no"
        print(uri)
        mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, my_tuple[x], 'delimitedtext')
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
        mem_layer.loadNamedStyle("C:\Layer_styles\style3.qml")
        x+=1
    except:
        break
```

All layers in the specific folder are added as new layers, but only with the default style. What am I missing?

Comment: maybe is the path, try using `r"C:\Layer_styles\style3.qml"` and after `mem_layer.triggerRepaint()`

Comment: Thank you Fran! That solved my problem beautifully!

Comment: I put my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use this path format `r"C:\Layer_styles\style3.qml"` and after repaint layer,using this `mem_layer.triggerRepaint()`